# How to download Groovy in local?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

As soon we click on the Windows Installer community version.
[image]

But the page doesn't allow to register user.

Can some one help for the same.

Thanks
Abhay

Either the jfrog page should allow me to register and download or it should start download automatically.

Comment: not clear what you are doing on jfrog page. here is the official groovy download page: https://groovy.apache.org/download.html

Comment: That's for the Windows installer community version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this URL, I got it from the official site:

https://groovy.jfrog.io/ui/native/dist-release-local/groovy-windows-installer/groovy-4.0.6/

This URL takes me directly to downloads.